# How to load data in MySQL from txt file which has both field name and value in a row?

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I am a newbie in `MySQL` but not in programming. I am trying to load a txt file with following data in `MySQL`:

```
{"id": "5bf573b81c5a1dcdd96ec666", "DisplayName": "Eureka", "NormalizedName": "eureka", "JournalId": "465895"}  
{"id": "5bf573b81c5a1dcdd96ec667", "DisplayName": "The Artist and Journal of Home Culture", "NormalizedName": "the artist and journal of home culture", "JournalId": "1137746"}  
{"id": "5bf573b81c5a1dcdd96ec668", "DisplayName": "Cumberland Law Review", "NormalizedName": "cumberland law review", "JournalId": "2978343"}
```

Each line is in second brackets, containing column names and quoted value separated by semicolon. I would like to have a table with these column names tabulating their respective values without any punctuation mark. For two column data file, I did it manually with the following code:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS venue_linking_pairs;
CREATE TABLE venue_linking_pairs (mid VARCHAR(40), aid VARCHAR(40)); -- optimise the field length
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/venue_linking_pairs.txt' 
INTO TABLE venue_linking_pairs
FIELDS terminated by ','
(mid, aid)
SET 
mid = SUBSTRING(mid, 10, 24) , 
aid = SUBSTRING(aid, 10, 24) ;
SELECT * FROM venue_linking_pairs ORDER BY mid LIMIT 10;
```

I would like do it more automatically e.g. setting the number of the table columns in `MySQL` equal to the txt data file, making their name same to the txt file one, removing the punctuation mark automatically without manually check the characters and use the substring function. I would be grateful for your help.

Comment: Have you done your use-case analysis, and thought about using NoSQL Databases like Mongo?

Comment: I would be tempted to use a dash of application code to decode this json prior to insertion

Comment: Load data into temporary table - one line per record. Then parse loaded data using JSON functions and store it into your table in another query.